# Pandas conditional copy of string data from one row to another

Tags: python, pandas, firewall

The following dataframe contains configuration items from a network firewall. Each row represents a configuration item - for example row `0` is for `object network fake1` and the only parameter associated with this is shown in `col_0` and is an IP address string `host 10.0.0.1`

Further down on `col_0` is an entry `network-object object fake1` and this refers to the aforementioned  `object network fake1` (there is a string pattern to work from). I want to copy the text from the IP address cell into the destination cell as follows:

[image]

Can anyone help me create a new dataframe with the following **desired output**:

**Please note** the names i.e. fake1, fake2, prt-apps etc can change but the strings "object network", "object-group network" and "network-object object" will always be the same so any code that matches based cross referencing names would be ideal and would scale with larger configs.

i.e. it could be `object network foo` and `network object object foo`.  There is a pattern to match on as can be seen further below.

[image]

**Test Data** to reproduce this can be taken from the `df.to_dict()` output here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

    dfData = {'col_0': {'object network fake1': ' host 10.0.0.1',
  'object network fake2': ' host 10.0.0.2',
  'object network fake3': ' host 10.0.0.3',
  'object network fake4': ' host 10.0.0.4',
  'object network fake5': ' host 10.0.0.5',
  'object-group network prt-apps': ' network-object object fake1',
  'object-group network prt-apps2': ' network-object object fake4',
  'object-group network prt-apps3': ' network-object object fake5'},
 'col_1': {'object network fake1': nan,
  'object network fake2': nan,
  'object network fake3': nan,
  'object network fake4': nan,
  'object network fake5': nan,
  'object-group network prt-apps': ' network-object object fake2',
  'object-group network prt-apps2': ' group-object prt-apps',
  'object-group network prt-apps3': ' group-object prt-apps2'},
 'col_2': {'object network fake1': nan,
  'object network fake2': nan,
  'object network fake3': nan,
  'object network fake4': nan,
  'object network fake5': nan,
  'object-group network prt-apps': ' network-object object fake3',
  'object-group network prt-apps2': nan,
  'object-group network prt-apps3': nan}}

pd.DataFrame(dfData)
```

What have I tried?

It has taken me hours to parse the data and get it to the format in this post. I have then looked into string manipulation with pandas but see `str.contains` is limited to a `Series` and can't parse the entire df. I thought about `groupby` but have no idea how this could be done.  Appreciate any help.

Anyone working with Cisco firewalls will probably find this post due to the object configuration naming convention and may likewise find a solution to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a combo of regex and `str.contains` and `str.replace`:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(dfData)
for index in df.index: #loop through the index values
    match = re.search(r'(fake\d)', index) #search for the "fake" + a digit
    if match is not None:
        fakenumber = match.group(1) #extract fake number ie "fake1"
        for col in df.columns:
            if True in df[col].str.contains(fakenumber).tolist():
                df.loc[:, col] = df[col].str.replace(fakenumber, fakenumber + df.loc[index, 'col_0'])
```

`df`

[image]

Comment: just change the regex to whatever pattern you can come up with that works. I have no idea what the possible patterns are.

Comment: I modified your code as follows: `match = re.search(r'object network (\w+)', index) #match group on object name
    if match is not None:
        objMatch = match.group(1)
        for col in df.columns:
            if True in df[col].str.contains(r"\b%s\b"%objMatch).tolist():        
                df.loc[:, col] = df[col].str.replace(objMatch, objMatch + df.loc[index, 'col_0'])` and it gives the desired output.  Many thanks

Comment: if you have time to look I asked another similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777970/pandas-concat-dataframe-rows-based-on-regex?noredirect=1#comment70749547_41777970  many thanks