# Pandas concat dataframe rows based on regex

Tags: python, pandas

**Overview**

As per the example image below, I am trying to concat dataframe rows based on the following regex:

```
for row in df.index:
    if True in df.loc[row].str.contains("group-object").tolist():  
        l = df.loc[row].tolist()
        for i in l:
            match = re.search(r" group-object (\S+)", i)
            if match is not None:
                print (row,match.group(1))
```

Out:

```
('object-group network prt-apps2', 'prt-apps')
('object-group network prt-apps3', 'prt-apps2')
```

The regex is looking for the string `group-object` and the match capture group gives me the `group-object` name.  I then need to use this name against the df index and concat the row containing the capture name to the end of the current row.

**Example:**

In the example image we see that row index `object-group network prt-apps2` `col_1` contains the string `group-object prt-apps`.  This refers to the row above with index `object-group network prt-apps`.  I need to concat this row (as highlighted in the image) to the end of row index `object-group network prt-apps2`.

The same goes for any other row where the regex has a match.

[image: example]

I have managed to get this far but struggle to see how to use concat or similar to achieve this.

**Data:**

from `df.to_dict()`

```
dfData = {'col_0': {'object-group network prt-apps': ' network-object object fake-1 host 10.0.0.1',
  'object-group network prt-apps2': ' network-object object fake4 host 10.0.0.4',
  'object-group network prt-apps3': ' network-object object fake5 host 10.0.0.5'},
 'col_1': {'object-group network prt-apps': ' network-object object fake2 host 10.0.0.2 ',
  'object-group network prt-apps2': ' group-object prt-apps',
  'object-group network prt-apps3': ' group-object prt-apps2'},
 'col_2': {'object-group network prt-apps': ' network-object object fake3 host 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0',
  'object-group network prt-apps2': '-',
  'object-group network prt-apps3': '-'},
 'col_3': {'object-group network prt-apps': ' network-object object fake121',
  'object-group network prt-apps2': '-',
  'object-group network prt-apps3': '-'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dfData)
```

**Desired output:**

I would be more than happy to have the desired output like this which follows the pattern I specified above.

[image]

Even better if the data could be moved to the left to fill any cells currently with `-` in them but not essential.  The bottom row its the longest as it has nested objects and `object-group network prt-apps3` contains `group object prt-apps2` which subsequently contains `group object prt-apps`.

Comment: can you also post your desired data set?

Comment: Hi @MaxU thanks for posting.  I put together a quick example in excel - pls see updated post.

Comment: I don't beleive it can be done in a vectorized way... You may want to transpose your DF and add rows (instead of adding columns) if you have a moderate # of rows...

Comment: Ok @MaxU, understood thanks.  Transposed output would be great if this is possible.  The format output  is less important than the task of capturing the data for this example.